# Appending to list alternative workflow for JAX

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differential-equations, jax

I am working on an differential equation solver written in JAX.  A common workflow I come across is something like this:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import jit

# Function to integrate.
@jit
def dxdt(t, x):
   return -x**2

# Euler method for simplicity.
@jit
def integrator(f, t, x, dt):
    return x + f(t, x) * dt

t_arr = jnp.linspace(0, 10, 100)
dt = t_arr[1] - t_arr[0]

x_list = []

# initialize x.
x = 0.

for t in t_arr:
    x_list.append(x)
    x = integrator(f, t, x, dt)

x_arr = jnp.array(x_list)
```

My question is if there is a way to 'vectorize' that for-loop using JAX?

I recognize that `jax.vmap()` would not be appropriate here, since the variable x is being changed in each for-loop iteration. If there a more JAX-friendly approach to this workflow?

Comment: Rename `integrator` to `stepper` and put the time loop into a new `integrator` function that returns the computed list of values. This function you can then decorate with `jit`. The computation (in the general case) is sequential in nature, there is nothing to parallelize. But if you can replace the python loop by some compiled variant, this should give a speed-up.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of sequential operation, where each step is dependent on the last, is supported in JAX via [`jax.lax.scan`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scan.html). Here's how you might do the equivalent of your computation using `scan`:

```py
import jax

def scan_body(carry, t):
  x, dt = carry
  new_x = integrator(dxdt, t, x, dt)
  return (new_x, dt), x

_, x_arr = jax.lax.scan(scan_body, (0., dt), t_arr)
```